# Custom UITextField Delegate method shouldChangeCharactersIn is not getting called

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

In my custom `UITextField`, `textFieldDidBeginEditing()` and `textFieldDidEndEditing()` delegate methods are getting called but 
`func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool`

```
@IBDesignable class CustomUITextField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate{

   //getting Called
   @objc func textFieldDidBeginEditing() {

    }

   //getting Called
    @objc func textFieldDidEndEditing(){

    }

    //Not getting Called
    @objc func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    }

}
```

I don't know why is not getting called. Any extra work needs to be done for that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please show the original code if possible.

Comment: @Rakesha Shastri sorry I cant show the  original code here

Comment: The only conclusion people can come to from seeing the current piece of code is that you haven't set the delegate properly. But that also seems to be not the reason since you say the first two delegates are getting called.

Comment: try delegate in awakeFromNib() method

Comment: @Devil Decoder excellent! it's working after adding delegate in awakeFromNib(). Thank you so much.

Comment: textfeild in xib or storyborad ???

Comment: @Sh_Khan textfeild in xib

Comment: @chimbu it should work without awakeFromNib see demo https://github.com/ShKhan9/CustomTexF

Comment: but now there will be problem like how you will transfer that delegate method call back to your ViewController for that you have to make your custom delegate and pass you delegate call back to your custome delegate method

Comment: @Sh_Khan your project not working after I connect delegate to *File's owner* in XIB

Comment: don't connect anything launch and test it directly

Comment: without connection is working.

Comment: @ Devil Decoder can you share some for transfer delegate back to ViewController

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the delegate

```
@IBDesignable class CustomUITextField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate{

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.delegate = self
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

          self.delegate = self
    }

    //getting Called
    @objc func textFieldDidBeginEditing() {

        print("textFieldDidBeginEditing")
    }

    //getting Called
    @objc func textFieldDidEndEditing(){

        print("textFieldDidEndEditing")
    }

    //Not getting Called
    @objc func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        print("shouldChangeCharactersIn")

        return true

    }

}
```

Comment: I have set the delegate in  override init(frame: CGRect) and required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) but still not working

Comment: No, weak only @IBOutlet weak var pinCodeTextField: CustomUITextField!

Comment: check if you override the delegate in the VC containing it

Comment: @Sh_Khan I use `override var delegate: UITextFieldDelegate? {
        get { return userDelegate }
        set { userDelegate = newValue }
    }` to call `shouldChangeCharactersIn` delegate method. But my regex that is supposed to get checked in this delegate is getting blocked due to the get and set of delegate. What can the solution be?